# SystemNotification Phonegap (Android)

Tags: android, notifications, jquery-mobile, system, cordova

I just recently started doing some Android app development, based on Phonegap (due to my web based background (PHP/MySQL)) and jQuery mobile. First tests are promising, but the next level is a bit too much for me.

I'm trying to integrate this plugin: https://github.com/saileshmittal/phonegap-system-notification-plugin

I have followed the readme file and my app seemed to be working fine (no notifications just yet but also no errors) but when I opened my project this morning, Eclipse showed the following errors:

- Invalid ZIP archive: src/com/phonegap/myapp/SystemNotification.java [in myapp]
- Invalid preference page path: XML Syntax

Next to this error, I don't quite understand how to show the system notification. I have tried the following:

```
navigator.SystemNotification.createStatusBarNotification('contentTitle', 'contentText', 'tickerText');
```

and:

```
navigator.systemNotification = new SystemNotification();
navigator.SystemNotification.createStatusBarNotification('contentTitle', 'contentText', 'tickerText');
```

Again, my background is web based. I'm familiar with PHP, MySQL, Javascript, jQuery, etc. but Java is completely new to me. The objective to my app at this point is to show some checkboxes (loaded from an external server) and save which ever checkbox is checked. This seems to be working fine. I'm testing showing the checked ones as a system notification. Seeing I have an Android powered phone, I'm working off that right now, planning to port it to iPhone and other devices later on.

If somebody could point me in the direction of push notification for later purposes, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Did you ever work out what the problem was?